# How to fix it : "could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm making API to return result as `JSON`

```
 public CompletionStage<Result> update(Long id) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        Building building = service.updateBuilding(id, request().body().asJson());
        return ok(Json.toJson(building));
    }, ec.current()).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return badRequest();
    });
}
```

Exception occurred:

> - Exception : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>     models.device.Building.Floors, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>     (through reference chain: models.device.Building["floors"])

But api for create is correctly working ....

```
public CompletionStage<Result> create() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        Building building = service.createBuilding(request().body().asJson());
        return ok(Json.toJson(building));
    }, ec.current()).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return badRequest();
    });
}
```

My Questions

- how to fix it
- why it was just happened except create is called

Detail codes

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Buildings")
public class Building {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "device_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_deviaes")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "device_sequence")
@Column(name = "building_device_id")
private Long id;

@Column (name = "building_id", unique = true)
private Integer buildingId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "building_device_id")
private List<Floor> Floors;

@NotNull
@Column (name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
```

**Controller**

```
public CompletionStage<Result> create() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        Building building = service.createBuilding(request().body().asJson());
        return ok(Json.toJson(building));
    }, ec.current()).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return badRequest();
    });
}

public CompletionStage<Result> update(Long id) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        Building building = service.updateBuilding(id, request().body().asJson());
        return ok(Json.toJson(building));
    }, ec.current()).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return badRequest();
    });
}
```

**Service**

```
public Building createBuilding(JsonNode jsonNode) {
    return LukeJPA.withSharedTransaction(() -> {
        return buildingDAO.create(jsonNode).get();
    });
}

public Building updateBuilding(Long id, JsonNode jsonNode) {
    return LukeJPA.withSharedTransaction(() -> {
        Building building = null;
        try {
            building = buildingDAO.update(id, jsonNode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return building;
    });
}
```

Comment: and what line of your code throws this? when the object is no longer "managed" by JPA ? ...

Comment: " return ok(Json.toJson(building)) " in Update function of Controller

Comment: so if the building object is no longer managed by an EntityManager then you need to make sure ALL fields you need are loaded before closing the EntityManager